# Calculating score on a quiz test using asp.net C# with database

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I'm trying to create a quiz in web application in asp.net C# using a database. The quiz has 25 question and 5 answers and each answer has a number of points(totally agree(1),agree(2), not sure(3), disagree(4), totally disagree(5)).

The questions and answers are in a database.
What I want is when i click on the submit button to calculate the score from those questions and put the score in a table from my database.
I try to do a if (radiobutton1.checked){
score=2}
but it doesn't work because of the repeater...I guess i'm not sure.
I try to delete the repeater but when i done that the questions and answers do not display on the web page.

In my aspx file i write code to display my data from database like that(using a repeater and table):

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> <%#Eval("IDq") %> )  <%#Eval("qustion") %></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ans1")%>' GroupName="quiz" Value="1"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ans2") %>' GroupName="quiz" Value="2"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("an3") %>' GroupName="quiz" Value="3"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ans4") %>' GroupName="quiz" Value="4"></asp:RadioButton>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ans5") %>' GroupName="quiz" Value="5"></asp:RadioButton>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr> </table>
</ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you have a good start.

And I am going to suggest that in place of the RadioGroup tag?

That DOES get you automatic ONLY one choice. The problem is we STILL will have to check all 5 controls.

A better control in this case to use what is called a RadioButtonList. It works VERY much like having used RadioGroup, but the REALLY nice part?

It is ONE control, and if there are 3 or 15 choices for Radio button group, it as ONE control returns

```
the index of the selection (0 to N)
the text value of the selection
the value value of the selection.
```

So I recommend using a RadioButton list - since it is "one thing" that returns the selections.

The "major" problem with the RadioButtonList is you CAN'T use those cool data bound expresisons ike you are using now (that was a good call/design on your part).

However, either we write a loop to "get/check" the 5 raido buttons, or we write a loop to fill the Radiobutton list - I think using code to fill out the RadioButton list is a better choice.

Also, you new - and I see you are attempting to use some "table and "tr" to help you lay out things. You don't really need this.

Now, because ALL of the above ideas saves us so much time, so much code? Well, then we can add extra code to say

```
 show the score and results after we submit
 tell the user they did NOT answer a question - they MUST!!!
 heck, toss is a cool check box, or X box to show wrong or right.
 Allow a question to only have say 2 answers - not always all 5
```

Ok first up, our table - it looks like this:

[image]

So, we have the IDq (id of question). The 1 to 5 possible answers, and then a column with the CORRECT answer.

Ok, now our markup. As I stated, since we reduced so much markup and code, then I added the message in big bold red that appears when a user did not answer all questions.

And I also added a "results" box that shows when you hit submit (number wrong, and correct).

So, now our Markup becomes like this:

```
    <div style="width:35%">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div style="float:left">
            <asp:Label ID="Question" runat="server" 
                Text = '<%# Eval("IDq").ToString + " ) " + Eval("question") %>' 
                Font-Size="X-Large">
            </asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right">
                <img id="MyImage" runat="server" src="" height="48" width="48" />
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both">

            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ></asp:RadioButtonList>
            </div>
            <br />
            <hr></hr>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>

        <asp:Button ID="cmdDone" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

        <div id="MyError" style="display:none;normal;color:red" runat="server">
            <h2>You have not answered all questions</h2>
            <h2>Please answer all questions before submitting</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="Results" runat="server" style="clear:both; display:none" >
            <h2>Results</h2>
            <asp:TextBox ID="MyCorrect" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="InCorrect" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>

    </div>
```

so, not a lot of markup - and we added quite a bit new features.

I also tossed in the idea to show a check box for correct, and wrong - you can remove that part - but it does help you learn a lot here.

So, now when I run the code, I see this:

[image]

So note the questions I have correct. As I stated - you may well want to remove that.

And note the message that I not yet answered all questions.

So, as noted, we have a LITTLE bit more code to load up the Repeater, but less to check things after.

So, our code now looks like this:

```
private DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        LoadData();
        ViewState["MyTable"] = MyTable;
    }
    else
        MyTable = ViewState["MyTable"];
}

public void LoadData()
{
    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblQuestions ORDER BY IDq",
                             new SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)))
    {
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
        MyTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader);
        Repeater1.DataSource = MyTable;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item | e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataRow MyRow = MyTable.Rows(e.Item.ItemIndex);

        RadioButtonList rBtnList = e.Item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            var strR = "ans" + i;
            if (IsDBNull(MyRow(strR)) == false)
            {
                ListItem nItem = new ListItem(MyRow(strR), i);
                rBtnList.Items.Add(nItem);
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void cmdDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // check all rows - make sure all have a answer
    // show check box for correct answers
    // total up correct answers (count)
    // total up wrong answers (count)

    MyError.Style("Display") = "none";


    int Correct = 0;
    int Wrong = 0;
    int NotAnser = 0;

    foreach (RepeaterItem ritem in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        RadioButtonList RadioBut = ritem.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");

        if (RadioBut.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            HtmlImage MyImage = ritem.FindControl("MyImage");
            if (MyTable.Rows(ritem.ItemIndex).Item("Answer") == RadioBut.SelectedIndex + 1)
            {
                Correct += 1;
                MyImage.Src = "/Content/ok.png";
            }
            else
            {
                Wrong += 1;
                MyImage.Src = "/Content/reject.png";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NotAnser += 1;
        }
    }

    // if missed questions then display warning.

    if (NotAnser > 0)
        MyError.Style("Display") = "normal";
    else
    {
        MyCorrect.Text = "Correct answers = " + Correct;
        InCorrect.Text = "Wrong answers = " + Wrong;
        Results.Style("Display") = "normal";
    }
}
```

So you can see in that submit button code, we are NOW with great ease to loop the repeater, get the user answer, check against the table data.

And note the other trick - I persist MyTable into ViewState. I did this since I did not want to have to re-load the table each time - it just means for ANY button click, control and code behind? I ALWAYS have the data table at my fingertips

Now, given the above does total up the answer, then you would have to add 2-5 more lines of code to write out the total, or the results - it not clear if you plan to have some other table where you have say some student ID, or user id, and you save the total results of the test (or the correct count, or wrong count).

so, the final result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. But my quiz doesn't have wrong or right answers. just answers with a particular number of points each. (e.g. question 1 (ans1 [1p] , ans 2[2p]....ans5[5p] and so on for all the questions. when click the submit button it has to sum up the score for all the questions. E.g. for question 1 -answer 2 being choose(has 2p) and question 2- answer 1 being choose(has 1p) the button should do  2+1 final result 3 p

Comment: do u know how can i do that? :)

Comment: You would need the 5 questions (text) as we show above in table. We have one column for the correct answer. You only need ONE more column that has the points awarded for correct answer. If you award points for wrong answers, then you need 5 extra columns for each of the points for each possible 5 questions. If there is only one correct answer, then only 1 extra column to hold the points awarded for the correct answer is required.  Above code shows how we total up correct and wrong answers. That code is EASY changed to add up points for correct answer with a question points column.

Comment: Give that you don't have a wrong or right answer? Then you need 5 extra columns Points1, Points2, points3..points5. So you need to have in the database the number of points you want for each qeustion. (unless they are all to be 1 point for ans1, 2 points for ans2 etc. But if the points to be awarded for each question is some number, then just add 5 extra columns to hold the points for each answer. Then you can use darn near exact code posted to total up the answer given - in place of adding +1 like the code does, simply add the Points1-Point5 column value for the answer given.